# Find basis of transformation which goes from one vector space to another

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

I've come across this question in a university exam paper. It's causing me a huge headache due to the fact that it goes from one vector space to another ($\def\R{\Bbb R}\R^3 \to \R^2$), otherwise it would be fairly standard. If anyone could shed some light on what I'm missing it would be much appreciated.

A4. Let $T : \R^3 → \R^2$ be given by
$T((x, y, z)) = (2x + 3y − 5z, x − 2y + z)$.

(i) Find a basis for the kernel $\ker T$ of $T$.

(ii) Find a basis for the image $\operatorname{im}T$ of $T$.

Comment: What are your attempts, what do you believe the kernel and image of the map to be?

Comment: Why is the fact that source and destination space are different causing you any trouble? These notions are well separated in the definitions of kernel and image: the kernel is a subspace of the source space, and the image a subspace of the destination space. Just apply the definitions.

Answer (score 1):

A standard method is to begin with the matrix representation of $T$: denoting by $e_1$, $e_2$ and $e_3$ the vectors in the standard basis of $\mathbb{R}^3$, we have
$$
T(e_1)=\begin{bmatrix}2\\1\end{bmatrix}
\qquad
T(e_2)=\begin{bmatrix}3\\-2\end{bmatrix}
\qquad
T(e_3)=\begin{bmatrix}-5\\1\end{bmatrix}
$$
so we have
$$
T\begin{bmatrix}x\\y\\z\end{bmatrix}=
\begin{bmatrix}
2 & 3 & -5 \\
1 & -2 & 1
\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}x\\y\\z\end{bmatrix}
$$
The kernel and image of $T$ are the same as the null space and the column space of the representing matrix. With Gaussian elimination
$$
\begin{bmatrix}
2 & 3 & -5 \\
1 & -2 & 1
\end{bmatrix}
\to
\begin{bmatrix}
1 & 3/2 & -5/2 \\
1 & -2 & 1
\end{bmatrix}
\to
\begin{bmatrix}
1 & 3/2 & -5/2 \\
0 & -7/2 & 7/2
\end{bmatrix}
\to
\begin{bmatrix}
1 & 3/2 & -5/2 \\
0 & 1 & -1
\end{bmatrix}
\to
\begin{bmatrix}
1 & 0 & -1\\
0 & 1 & -1
\end{bmatrix}
$$
This means that the matrix has rank $2$, so the column space is $\mathbb{R}^2$. Hence the map $T$ is surjective: any basis of $\mathbb{R}^2$ will do, in particular
$$
\left\{
\begin{bmatrix}2\\1\end{bmatrix},
\begin{bmatrix}3\\-2\end{bmatrix}
\right\}
$$
(the pivot columns). However also the standard basis would do.

The last matrix also shows that the null space is generated by the vector
$$
\begin{bmatrix}1\\1\\1\end{bmatrix}
$$
which forms a basis for the kernel of $T$.

Comment: I believe that the first matrix should have top left entry '2' and hence the whole row reduction should be different - hopefully giving my answer...

Comment: @SEWillB Oh, yes! Let me fix it.

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming since you are a university student that you know the rank-nullity theorem- and hopefully it's proof! We take a basis for the kernel of the linear map, call the map $T$ between vector spaces $V$ and $W$;
Say $\{v_1,...,v_m\} $ is a basis for $ker(T)$
Extend to a basis for $V$, say $\{v_1,...,v_m, u_1, ..., u_n\}$ so $dim(V)=n+m$
Then $\{T(u_1),...,T(u_n)\}$ is a basis for the image of $T$.
Applying that to this case, we first need to find a basis for $ker(T)$, do this however you wish (row-reduction of matrix defining T or just solving the simultaneous equations you need to - both are equivalent.)
You should find that the vector $[1, 1, 1]$ is a basis for the kernel of T -(If I've done this correctly).
Extend this in any way you see fit to a basis for $\Bbb{R}^3$ say, add in $[1, 0, 0]$ and $[0, 1, 0]$. Apply $T$ to these and you'll have you're basis for $Im(T)$
As a check you can check that $T([1, 0, 0]) = [2, 1]$ and $T([0, 1, 0]) = [3, -2]$ are linearly independent...
Hope this helps!